# How to auto select a matching subtitle in web movie player?

Tags: php, html, video

I have a basic web video player that plays mkv and mp4 files, my video playlist is like this:

```
movie1.mkv
movie2.mkv
movie3.mkv
movie4.mkv
movie5.mkv
```

I also have `vtt` subtitles for each of those movies, they are named like this:

```
movie1.vtt
movie2.vtt
movie3.vtt
movie4.vtt
movie5.vtt
```

When clicking a movie from my playlist, I want to be able to auto select the subtitle, so for instance when I click `movie3.mkv` then `movie3.vtt` is also selected so it can display the proper subtitle for that movie. How can I do that? This is my script http://pastebin.com/m7bbJbqF

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes, I tried to edit the html with a subtitle but didn't work